# Java SQL CallableStatement - use "current + interval (5)" as a parameter

Tags: java, sql, informix

I have a callablestatement which creates an offer in the db. The offer is to start in the future, in 5 minutes actually.

My code currently looks like

```
String sqlCall = "{call pInsOffer ( ?, ?, ?, ? )}" ;
try (CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall()) {
  callableStatement.setString("offerName", "My Offer") ;
  callableStatement.setString("offerCashBack", "10.00" ) ; 
  callableStatement.setString("offerStartTime", "current + interval(5) second to second" ); 
  callableStatement.setString("offerEndTime", "current + interval(1) day to day") ;
  ResultSet rs = callableStatement.executeQuery() ;
}
```

Which results in a "Non-numeric character in datetime or interval." exception.

I assume that this is because of the String "current + ..." (which is fine when run against the db directly), is there a way that I can set this as NOT a string so that it will be recognised as the current time command?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
callableStatement.setTimestamp("offerStartTime", new Timestamp(now + 5 * 1000)); 
callableStatement.setTimestamp("offerEndTime", new Timestamp(now + 24 * 3600 * 1000));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wont work as the machine that java is running on is not the same as the db, and may even be in a different time zone. I have no control over the db or procs, they are managed externally.

Comment: Timestamp does not have timezone, it's GMT and JDBC driver knows that

Comment: the issue is that you are using the time stamp from the client machine. if there is a delay in the communication, or a high load on the client causes java to delay past the 5 seconds, the timestamp isnt valid any more, and the offer cant be created.

So my issue is that the time is not necessarily in the past by the time the callable statement is being executed. I want it to use the db time at execution. Otherwise the offer is not valid.

Comment: I see, then you could change the proc to take offerStartTime and offerEndTime as integers and make the calculations in proc body

Comment: unfortunately, part of the problem is that i can't, they are 3rd party procs.

Comment: Currently, my way of overcoming this is to use a time definitely in the future (tomorrow) and then use a simple 
'update toffer set offerStartTime = current + interval(5) second to second where offerId = 1234 ;'